# How to save UIImage from UIImagePicker in Documents folder and get string for path to save in Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiimage

I'm building my first Swift application. In it, the user needs to be able to choose an image from the iPhone's photo library. Then I want to save this image to keep permanently for use in other parts of the app.

I know it is possible to convert a `UIImage` to `NSData` and save as binary data in Core Data, but I have read that it is a bad idea to store Binary Large Objects, such as images directly in Core Data.

I have seen it suggested that you should save the image file in the Documents folder and then just save a string for the file path in Core Data. But I haven't seen an actual example of the code snippet needed to do this.

Steps to accomplish:

1. get `UIImage` from image picker. (this part I've got working)
2. save the image data in Documents folder
3. get string value for the file path to Documents folder
4. save this string in Core Data
5. Do steps 2-4 in reverse elsewhere in the app to use the stored
   image.

Here is the code for the `UIImagePicker` that I'm starting with:

```
@IBAction func openImagePicker(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary){
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!)
{
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
myImageView.image = image
}
```

So the `UIImage` displayed in `myImageView`.image is what I need to do something with.

Comment: Do you need to use Core Data ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The string representing a file path to the image will be an attribute of an existing type of Core Data entity, which is central to the app. I've got Core Data all set up and working in the app already. The Core Data part is not really the problem. All I really need is how to save the image in the folder and get a string for it's location.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your image with following code

```
    let imageData = NSData(data:UIImagePNGRepresentation(wineImage.image))
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    var docs: String = paths[0] as! String
    let fullPath = docs.stringByAppendingPathComponent("yourNameImg.png")
    let result = imageData.writeToFile(responseData, atomically: true)
```

Inside fullPath you'll find the complete path, the image will be stored in app's document dir.